# Replace DIV by another DIV with the help of OnClickButton

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page where I have such a GUI

[image: Page Example]

Now my real problem is that as soon as I Click on new Button, it shall replace the whole div (Container) starting from the top left of the box  till the end of the right box with a particular form.

The form should load on the same (Same container) page dynamically.
How should I do it?
If there is any code sample available then please do post it.

Comment: try $('#divid').load('myform.html');

Comment: ok. I didnt get it.
 As soon as the new button is clicked... the whole box of Employee Master should be replaced with the form as shown in the example.
Both the divs are within the same container..
[url=http://postimg.org/image/6uole44cv/][img]http://s27.postimg.org/6uole44cv/image.jpg[/img][/url]


so if possible can you please put the code in proper format
for the first image div id='employee_master_table'
for the second image div id='employee_master_form'

Kindly please help me out with actual jquery or html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know there are a few ways to achieve what you want, the first one is to use `$("#element-id").html("put your html code here")` or `$("#element-id").load("put your html file here")` which will replace anything inside the selected element .

Just in case you don't want to replace everything inside your div, instead adding some HTML tag you can use `$("#element-id").append("put your html code here")`.

For more info about those jQuery functions:

- [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
- [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Example:

HTML:

```
<button id="new-entry" class='btn btn-success btn-large'>
       <i class='icon-beer'> New Entry </i>
</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#new-entry").click( function(){
        $("#employee_master_table").load("ajax/employee_master_form.html #employee_master_form")
   });
});
```

Comment: So basically as per my first image the div name is  employee_master_table and the second image which is a form the div name is employee_master_form ....
so on the new button I should write the code as follows:
<button class='btn btn-success btn-large' onclick='$("#employee_master_table").load("ajax/employee_master.html #employee_master_form")'>
<i class='icon-beer'> New Entry </i>
</button>

Is it right ? if not then lemme know I shall put the code over here.

Comment: Well the problem is that such an example is repeated around 100 times throughout the whole application... 
So its not convenient to replace everytime with the HTML Page..
Lemme give you the code then may be you might get an idea of what exactly I am talking about...

Comment: Then you can try to use [.hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [.show](http://api.jquery.com/show/). Put your code in your question, so other people can see it right away..

Comment: <section id='content'>
<div class='container'>
<div clas='row' id='content-wrapper'>
<div class='col-xs-12'>

// This div is where you can see Employee Master at the header
<div class='row'>
</div>

//This div is for the table as shown in image1
<div class='row'>
</div>

//This div is for the buttons as you can see
<div class='row'>
</div>

//This div is for the form as shown in image2
<div class='row'>
</div>

</div> // col div close
</div> // Row cotainer-wrapper div close
</div> // Container div close
</section>

How to replace table div with form div with onclick button?